# Having trouble calling a constructor in scala when passing in a multidimensional array of enums

Tags: arrays, scala, class, enums

In my program, I have a Scala enum that looks like:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val v1, v2, v3, v4 = Value
}
```

And a class that requires a multidimensional array of this enum that is set up like:

```
class MyClass(arr: Array[Array[MyEnum.Value]]) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that when I try to initialize a new object of MyClass, I get the error:

> Expression of type Array[Array[MyEnum.Value]] does not conform to expected type Array[Array[MyEnum.type]]

But my expected type should be Array[Array[MyEnum.Value]] as per the type declaration on that parameter. I can even put a default value matching Array[Array[MyEnum]] and it will work, but if I try to feed in that very same value that I set as the default as an argument when trying to instantiate it, I'll get this error.

Does anyone know why Scala is doing this switch from Value to type?

Comment: What does the code look like for instantiating a `MyClass`?

Comment: val instance = new MyClass(Array.fill[MyEnum.Value](8,8)(MyEnum.v1)) The array fill works fine if used to provide a default value for the array in the class, however, when passed in, it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
     |   val v1, v2, v3, v4 = Value
     | }
defined object MyEnum

scala> class MyClass(arr: Array[Array[MyEnum.Value]]) {}
defined class MyClass

scala> val ea = Array(Array(MyEnum.v1, MyEnum.v2), Array(MyEnum.v3, MyEnum.v4))
ea: Array[Array[MyEnum.Value]] = Array(Array(v1, v2), Array(v3, v4))

scala> val mc = new MyClass(ea)
mc: MyClass = MyClass@3a861417
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was an error on my part writing up the post. It is an object in my project.

Comment: So how are you instantiating the `MyClass`?

Comment: In a clone method on the class:

    def clone(): MyClass = {
      val newInstance = new MyClass(this.arr.clone())
      ...
    }

Comment: But you can only invoke `clone` on an instance, so what does the code that creates this instance look like?

Comment: val instance = new MyClass(Array.fill[MyEnum.Value](8,8)(MyEnum.v1))
The array fill works fine if used to provide a default value for the array in the class, however, when passed in, it gives the error.